# How can I open a UNC path from Linux in Java?

Tags: java, linux, unc

Are there any libraries available that will allow me to read from and write to a Windows Fileshare given a UNC path from Java on Linux.

It's trivial on a windows box itself, and I'm aware of smbclient approaches, but I'm looking to do it by dropping in a library.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have a look at [jcifs](http://jcifs.samba.org/).  It sounds like what you are looking for.

From the jcifs site:

> JCIFS is an Open Source client library that implements the CIFS/SMB networking protocol in 100% Java. CIFS is the standard file sharing protocol on the Microsoft Windows platform (e.g. Map Network Drive ...). This client is used extensively in production on large Intranets.